# Regex for ATM Approved Cash Withdrawal Transaction in Electronic Journal Logs

Tags: c#, regex, logging

I have a file of ATM Electronic Journal which contains logs of all activities performed on ATM. Now I want to extract the transaction logs highlighted in BOLD Text through Regex.

```
DATE: 26/07/22   TIME: 17:42:24
ATM ID: 9074
STAN: 886373   RRN: 220717886373
PAN: 621657*******089
TXN: INVALID TRAN SEQ: 0915
STATUS: CUST NOT FOUND
17:42:28 OPCODE = FACF  A 
17:42:38 OPCODE = FAA  DA 
17:42:47 NOTES STACKED
17:42:50 CARD TAKEN
17:42:54 NOTES PRESENTED 2,3,1,9

**DATE: 26/07/22   TIME: 17:42:37
ATM ID: 9074
STAN: 887059   RRN: 220717887059
PAN: 621657*******089
A/C: 0622******3203      20586
TXN: WITHDRAWAL SEQ: 0917
AMOUNT:   50000.00
C1 [2], C2 [3], C3 [1], C4 [9]
STATUS: APPROVED
CASH TOTAL       TYPE1 TYPE2 TYPE3 TYPE4
DISPENSED        00262 00270 00118 00180
REJECTED         00010 00013 00008 00009
REMAINING        01338 01730 01882 00320
17:42:55 NOTES TAKEN
17:43:04 TRANSACTION END**
*444*26/07/2022*17:43*
*TRANSACTION STARTED*
CARD INSERTED
17:43:15 OPCODE =   CAD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should match your bold text:

```
(DATE\:).+(TRANSACTION END)
```

It checks for text which is in between "DATE:" and "TRANSACTION END"

https://regexr.com/6rmsr

Comment: Please check on http://regexstorm.net/tester. It is  not working  there.

Comment: Yes its working there. but problem is EJ logs are printed line by line and this regex will not work. I tried to paste the exact logs in stack overflow but it automatically remove all carriage return and write them in a single line. see here the actual log format. https://ctxt.io/2/AADg55QNFg